# Why do I get an error when using dml on pentaho 'SQL EDITOR' in table output

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I want to change data values

### ex)
AS-IS A Table - AA column - 'asisdata'

TO-BE B Table - BB column - 'tobedata'

This process is possible with the following sql query, right?

```
UPDATE B SET BB = 'tobedata'
WHERE BB = 'asisdata';
```

but I can't used this query

Which function should I use to modify the data and put it into the TO-BE table?

I tried this root

1. input table -> insert/update -> output table
2. input table -> update -> output table
3. input table -> execute SQL script -> output table

Comment: Please add the exact query you are running and the output you get from it. It's easier to get help for coding with specific questions, instead of broad ones.

Comment: Why can't you use the 2nd option? You use the Input table step where you have two columns AA with 'asisdata' and CC with 'tobedata', or, if you can't create a query to get CC column, you add the steps you need after the Input table to add the CC column. After that, you use the Update step on your table B and provide the WHERE BB = AA and SET BB = CC.